# HTML reponse after Ajax call is stripped of some tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making an ajax call to a action in a controller which returns a partial view. The partial view is a row that will be appended or it will replace an existing row from a grid of items (depending if I am adding or editing a row item).
In the Network tab from Google Chrome I am getting the correct string of HTML like:

```
<tr class="" data-id="1c4daceb-2afb-413b-8adc-d20b4d8969e5">
    <td><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="http://localhost/Project/6b39488b-db2d-495e-957c-ede0eb462292.png" data-id="1c4daceb-2afb-413b-8adc-d20b4d8969e5"/></td>
    <td>bvcbvX</td>
    <td>6b39488b-db2d-495e-957c-ede0eb462292.png</td> 
</tr>
```

but in my Ajax success function:

```
function onDataEdited(data, status, xmlhttp) { 
    alert(data);
}
```

I get the row stripped of  and  tags, like this:

```
<img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="http://localhost/Project/6b39488b-db2d-495e-957c-ede0eb462292.png" data-id="1c4daceb-2afb-413b-8adc-d20b4d8969e5"/> 
    bvcbvX
    6b39488b-db2d-495e-957c-ede0eb462292.png
```

So something from jquery strips my tags leaving only the content.

The call to the action is done through Ajax like this:

```
function MakeAjaxCall() {
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
        iframe: true, ---> here is needed since I am adding a file upload from my form
        beforeSubmit: function () { 
            if (!$('#myForm').valid())
                //process validation

            return $('#myForm').valid();
        },
        success: function (data, status, xmlhttp) {  
            if (xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('ErrorHeader') == null ||
                xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('ErrorHeader') == "") {

                //process success
            }
            else { 
                //process error
            } 
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr); 
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get my response data without being stripped of  and  tags?

I am using this jquery plugin (malsup.com/jquery/form) for making the form "ajaxified" in order to submit a form that contains files through Ajax. 
The 'ajaxForm' method from this plugin has as dataType only 'xml', 'json', 'script' and null - (which I am using) and the response is stil stripped of tags for 'xml'. If I set 'json' or 'script' it throws a client side errors specifying that it cannot parse the response (is trying to parse it as a script when it is html).

Comment: try using `$.post()` instead of `.ajaxForm`

Comment: I need to use ajaxForm since I am also loading an image when submitting the form and I need to set iFrame to true. Anyway the response that I am receiving in the Network (in Chrome) is exactly what I need, but after that it is stripped of <tr> and <td> and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the dataType: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object ?

Comment: I've tried with 'json' and 'script' for dataType and it throws a client side error. For 'xml' it can parse the response (no error being thrown). If I don't specify anything for dataType (default behavior) I get the stripped down response.

Comment: For 'xml' I can parse the response but it is still stripped of HTML tags.

Comment: jQuery also has text and html for datatypes in an ajax call. Try 'html' and see if that works?

Comment: I am using this jquery plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for making the form "ajaxified" in order to submit a form that contains files through Ajax. The 'ajaxForm' method from this plugin has as dataType only 'xml', 'json', 'script' and null - (which I am using). I have set in dataype 'html' and the response is stil stripped of tags.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the plugin not being able to handle HTML then - which would be weird as jquery has this built in. Maybe send the server response as JSON and parse the data into the HTML after the ajax call.